# How to get value of textbox dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Am adding three textbox dynamically on ADD button click...
These three textbox are in same div tag...
and each text box having different name...

so am creating new div having three textbox each time when I click on ADD button...

Now I want to access text field entered value... how to access??

```
    <div class="ord" id="parent">

    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary fa fa-plus add btn-xs"> Add </button>
```

JS

```
   var items = "<form role='form' class='form-inline' style='padding-bottom: 5px;'>"
                    + "<div class='form-group'><input id='med' placeholder='' class='form-control'></div>"
                    + "<div class='form-group' style='padding-left: 5px;'><input id='qua' placeholder='' class='form-control'></div>"
                    + "<div class='form-group' style='padding-left: 5px;'><input id='rem' placeholder='' class='form-control'></div>"

  $('.add').on("click",function(){
div_id = div_id + 1
$( ".ord" ).append('<div id="item'+div_id+'">' + items + '<button style="margin-left: 3px;" type="button" id="item'+div_id+'" class="btn btn-default btn-danger btn-xs fa fa-close" onclick=deleteitem(id)></button></form></div>');
   })
```

I have array of Id of all div tag... like [item1,item2,item3]

How to access all text field entered text ??

Comment: You are repeating same `id` values, which might fail.

Comment: There is several issues into you code. Please check my answer to find a complete, working, rework.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.forEach` and `concatenate` `id` with `#` while selecting element(to make it valid `ID` selector).

```js
['item1', 'item2', 'item3'].forEach(function(item) {
  $("#" + item).find('input').each(function() {
    console.log(this.value);
  });
});
```

**Edit:** If `item1,...` are `id` of `parent-div-elements`, Use `.find('input')` to find descendants `<input>` elements. `.each` could be used to iterate through all the *found* elements to get their `value`.

*Note:* You must pass `this.id` instead of `id` in `deleteitem(id)`

Comment: item1 is a div ... and in that div having three textbox... and I want to access entered value of that three text box... how?? In above answer it access div only

Answer (score 0):

```
var items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']; // this is your "array of Id of all div tag"
items.forEach(function(item) {
    $('#' + item).find('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
        console.log($(this).val());
    }):
});
```

You should probably add `type="text"` to your inputs.

---

Also, note that in **your code you will have several occurences** of the same id. That's definitly not good.

Here, find a better code to avoid that:

```js
var items = [];
var div_id = 0;

// Make a function so you have only one occurence of each #med, #qua and #rem
function getInputs(id) {
    var inputs = "";
    inputs += '<form role="form" class="form-inline">';
    inputs += '    <div class="form-group"><input type="text" id="med' + id + '" class="form-control" /></div>';
    inputs += '    <div class="form-group"><input type="text" id="qua' + id + '" class="form-control" /></div>';
    inputs += '    <div class="form-group"><input type="text" id="rem' + id + '" class="form-control" /></div>';
    inputs += '</form>';
    
    return inputs;
}

// When you click on your Add button
$(".add").on("click", function() {
    var currentId = "item" + div_id; // Only once occurence of #item0, #item1, etc.
    
    var html = "";
    html += '<div id="' + currentId + '">';
    html += getInputs(div_id);
    html += '    <button type="button" data-delete="' + currentId + '" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Close</button>';
    html += '</div>';
   
   $(".ord").append(html);
  
   items.push(currentId);
   div_id++;
});

// When you click on a Close button
// We use data-* attribute in order to identify if a button is a "close" one, and which element it should closes
$(document).on("click", "button[data-delete]", function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data("delete");
    
    $("#" + id).remove();
  
    // remove this element from the items
    var index = items.indexOf(id);
    if (index !== -1) {
        items.splice(index, 1);
    }
});


// When you change a value in one of your inputs
$(document).on("change", 'input[type="text"]', function() {
    items.forEach(function(item) {
        $('#' + item).find('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
            console.log($(this).attr("id") + " => " + $(this).val());
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="ord" id="parent">

</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary add">Add</button>
```